# Setting List items in C# without automatic setter/getter

Tags: c#, list, setter, getter

I'm trying to make a manual setter/getter method in C#, but i'm getting the following error from the "set"-line:
Error: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.ListPackage.Add(Package)' has some invalid arguments

```
private List<Package> packages = new List<Package>();    

public List<Package> Packages
{
    set { packages.Add(value); }
    get { return packages; }
}
```

Comment: The `setter` is called when you use the `=` operator, this operator checks for the `assignability` from the value (on the right side), so the right side value should always be `List<Package>`, that value is held by `value` in the `setter`, when you write this  `packages.Add(value)` in the setter, it is of course recoginized by the `IDE` that the `type` is invalid. (`value` should be of type `Package`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code should look like this.

```
private var packages = new List<Package>();    

public List<Package> Packages
{
    set { packages = value; }
    get { return packages; }
}
```

If you're trying to use the index getter/setter for some kind of passthrough:

```
public int this[int key]
{
    get
    {
        return Packages[key];
    }
    set
    {
        Packages[key] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**With a getter/setter the input and output types must be the same.** (hence the declaration being `public List<Package> Packages { ...` - it is expecting an input of `List<Packages>` and an output of `List<Packages>`.

What you are doing here is trying to `get` type `List<Package>` and `set` type `Package`. This is not allowed.

What I think you want to do is the following:

```
private List<Package> packages = new List<Package>();    

public List<Package> Packages
{
    // no setter
    get { return packages; }
}
```

Then call `myObject.Packages` to get all the packages and `myObject.Packages.Add(package)` to add.

Comment: But if i change it to set { packages.Add(Package); } i get "Package is a "type" but is used as a variable"

Comment: @MadsK I think you misunderstand. I updated my question to try and explain it better.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to add `value`, which is a `List<Package>`, to `packages` you should use

```
set { packages.AddRange(value); }
```

Otherwise,

```
set { packages = value; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that.

if you are trying to set an element you should...

```
public void addPackage(Package pack){
    packages.Add(pack);
}
```

usage:
    MyClass m= new MyClass();
    m.addPackage(new Package());

if you are trying to set the collection then ...

```
public List<Package> Packages
{
    set { packages=value; }
    get { return packages; }
}
```

usage:

```
MyClass m= new MyClass();
m.Packages=new List<Package>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have yourself a bit mixed up here.

The *type* of Packages is `List<Package>`.  When you're calling `packages.Add(value);`, `packages` is in fact, `List<Package>`.

```
public List <Package> Packages
{
    get { return packages; }
    set { packages = value; }
}
```

This corrects the property.

To add an item:

```
Packages.Add(myPackage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the `set{}` method as the `Add` method, which it isn't.  `set` is used to change the **entire collection** whereas an `Add` method would add an item to the collection.  what has been stated in other answers is correct... if you really want the `=` operator to add to the collection rather than assign a new collection, you can use `AddRange()` but for clarity sake, you should be overriding the `=` operator if that is the case.